# Perimeter of circumference using Laplace transform

Tags: geometry, laplace-transform

I wish to compute the perimeter of a circumference of unit radius by using the Laplace transform (just for fun). However, I am getting the wrong result by a factor of 2. Can someone help me find it?

I write $$P=\int dx dy \delta(x^2+y^2-1),$$ where the integral is over the whole plane. Then I introduce the auxiliary function $$P(t)=\int dx dy \delta(x^2+y^2-t).$$

The Laplace transform $f(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}P(t)dt$ gives 
$$f(s)= \int dx dy e^{-s(x^2+y^2)}=2\pi\int_0^\infty rdre^{-sr^2}=\frac{\pi}{s}.$$

Inverse Laplace transform then gives just $P(t)=\pi$.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Why do you use $\delta(x^2+y^2-1)$ and not $\delta(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the Laplace transform to see the problem. Notice that 
$$\int dxdy\delta(x^2+y^2-1)=2\pi\int_0^\infty rdr\delta(r^2-1)=2\pi\frac{1}{2}=\pi.$$

This is wrong because you should have $\delta(r-1)$ in there and not $\delta(r^2-1)$ (user md2perp2 has it right on his comment).

So you should start with $$P=\int dxdy\delta(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1)$$ and then it will work.

Comment: The difference is not geometrical, but analytical. Have a look at the discussion here: <http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath663/kmath663.htm>

Comment: Your link has an extra **>**. After correcting this error the server gives an *401.2 - Unauthorized* error.

Comment: I don't know why it won't let me edit the comment. Anyway, you are wrong. After removing the extra >, it works. I posted this in response to another comment, which was since then erased

Comment: Comments can't be edited after 5 min. And the 401.2 was a temporal problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is a more rigorous way. Let $D_\rho$ the disk centered at the origin with radius $\rho$ and $L$ the length of the unit circle. Since $\partial D_\rho$ is smooth we have
$$ L = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{\mu(D_{\rho+\varepsilon})-\mu(D_\rho)}{\varepsilon} \tag{1}$$
but on the other hand $\mu(D_\rho)=C\rho^2$, hence $L=2\mu(D_1)$. By Fubini's theorem
$$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-z^2}\,dz\right)^2 \tag{2} $$
and by parity and the Laplace transform
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-z^2}\,dz = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-z^2}\,dz = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{e^x\sqrt{x}}=\left(\mathcal{L}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)(1)=\sqrt{\pi}.\tag{3} $$
On the other hand, by Cavalieri's principle the LHS of $(2)$ equals

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} L\rho e^{-\rho^2}\,d\rho = \frac{L}{2}\tag{4}$$
hence by $(2),(3)$ and $(4)$ we have $L=2\pi$ and $\mu(D_1)=\pi$.

Comment: +1,What is $B_{\rho}$ and $\mu$ here ? @Jacj D'Aurizio ?

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light: $B_\rho$ was a typo,it should have been $D_\rho$, now fixed. $\mu$ is the usual Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lies in the use of the Delta Dirac distribution, a defining property of which states $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \mathrm{d}x = f(0)$$
In your case, after switching the limits of integration (a step itself that might require some justification), you get an integral over $t$ between $0$ and $\infty$  and not over the real line as the Delta Dirac distribution would require.
I think I saw a post here on MSE where the “audacious” pushed it forward, up to claiming $$ \int_{0 }^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{f(0)}{2}$$  explained to the laymen as myself by considering nascent delta functions symmetric with respect to the origin and observing their limit. I am sure one could find calcualtions where such approach operationally works, the kind of pindaric flights physicists often delight audiences with.

In this case, whose rigorous validity I am totally unqualified to comment upon, one might be tempted to think you are really computing only half of the circumference, which fits your result.

Comment: Since we have $\delta(x^2+y^2-t)$ and $x^2+y^2>0$, I don't think the limit of integration is the matter

Comment: @thedude, why not? from the operational point of view, your calculation works by placing an annulus around the circumference $x^2 + y^2 -1 = 0$, and the getting the limit as the annulus thickness goes to zero. Informally speaking, this is how you assign a "surface" value to a line (you are using an area integral to calculate the length of a curve). With half the region of Integration, you halving the area of the annulus.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
P & \equiv
\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}\delta\pars{x^{2} + y^{2} - 1}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{\verts{y} < 1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\bracks{{\delta\pars{x + \root{1 - y^{2}}} \over \verts{2x}} +
{\delta\pars{x - \root{1 - y^{2}}} \over \verts{2x}}}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{-1}^{1}\bracks{%
{1 \over 2\root{1 - y^{2}}} + {1 \over 2\root{1 - y^{2}}}}\,\dd y
\,\,\,\stackrel{y\ =\ \sin\pars{\theta}}{=}\,\,\,\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\dd\theta = \bbx{\pi}
\end{align}